# Cannot find the right overloaded NHibernate Execute function

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I can't find the overload function of NHibernate SchemaExport.Execute

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/28/nhibernate-unit-testing.aspx

What does this four booleans do?

```
new SchemaExport(Configuration).Execute(true, true, false, true, session.Connection, Console.Out);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NH2.1 the 4th bool parameter to SchemaExport.Execute() was eliminated. It indicated that you wanted the DDL nicely formatted. If you ask NH2.1+ to script the DDL to the console, it formats it nicely by default. No need for a separate option. Here is the signature from NH2.0...

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the Export of the Schema in the given connection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="script"><see langword="true" /> if the ddl should be outputted in the Console.</param>
    /// <param name="export"><see langword="true" /> if the ddl should be executed against the Database.</param>
    /// <param name="justDrop"><see langword="true" /> if only the ddl to drop the Database objects should be executed.</param>
    /// <param name="format"><see langword="true" /> if the ddl should be nicely formatted instead of one statement per line.</param>
    /// <param name="connection">
    /// The connection to use when executing the commands when export is <see langword="true" />.
    /// Must be an opened connection. The method doesn't close the connection.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="exportOutput">The writer used to output the generated schema</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method allows for both the drop and create ddl script to be executed.
    /// This overload is provided mainly to enable use of in memory databases. 
    /// It does NOT close the given connection!
    /// </remarks>
    public void Execute(bool script, bool export, bool justDrop, bool format,
                        IDbConnection connection, TextWriter exportOutput)
            -- remainder of method --
```